# Find shortest path between nodes with additional filter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to model flights between airports on certain dates. So far my test graph looks like this:

[image: graph]

Finding shortest path between for example LTN and WAW is trivial with:

```
MATCH (f:Airport {code: "LTN"}), (t:Airport {code: "WAW"}), 
p = shortestPath((f)-[]-(t)) RETURN p
```

Which gives me:

[image]

But I have no idea how to get only paths with Flights that have relation FLIES_ON with given Date.

[Link to Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/uvdh36)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would do with your given model. The other commenters' queries don't seem right, as they use `ANY()` instead of `ALL()`. You specifically said you only want paths where *all* `Flight` nodes on the path are attached to a given `Date` node with a `:FLIES_ON` relationship:

```
MATCH (LTN:Airport {code:"LTN"}),
      (WAW:Airport {code:"WAW"}), 
      p =(LTN)-[:ROUTE*]-(WAW)
WHERE ALL(x IN FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE x:Flight) 
          WHERE (x)<-[:FLIES_ON]-(:Date {date:"130114"}))
WITH p ORDER BY LENGTH(p) LIMIT 1
RETURN p
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/xgz84y

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using shortestPath or allShortestPaths will never include the Date nodes.

What you need to do is to filter the pattern with the date node (I don't know however how you store the date, so I'll take Ymd format:

```
MATCH (f:Airport {code: "LTN"}), (t:Airport {code: "WAW"})
MATCH p=(f)-[*]-(t)
WHERE ANY (r in rels(p) WHERE type(r) = 'FLIES_ON')
AND ANY (n in nodes(p) WHERE 'Date' IN labels(n) AND n.date = 20150120)
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p)
LIMIT 1
```

Another solution and less costly, is to include the date in your match and building yourself the path with it :

```
MATCH (n:Date {date:20150120})
MATCH (f:Airport {code:"LTN"}), (t:Airport {code:"WAW"})
MATCH p=(f)<-[*]-(n)-[*]->(t)
RETURN distinct(p)
ORDER BY length(p)
```

Comment: The first query doesn't return any paths for me, and the second one returns the correct one LO123 but also returns Flight nodes for W6123 and FR123. You can test them on the Neo console link I added to the question.

Comment: yep, I re-added shortestPath, but should be removed for only p

Answer (score 0):

though this would not be my preferred structure for this kind of data; in answering your question i might go this way instead. get the paths, filter the path and get the first one ordered by length.

in the console tests is runs faster than the one suggested above as the query plan is simpler.

Anyhoo i hope this at least points you in a good direction :)

```
MATCH (f:Airport { cd: "ltn" }),(t:Airport { cd: "waw" }), p =((f)-[r*]-(t))
WHERE ANY (x IN relationships(p) 
           WHERE type(x)='FLIES_ON') AND ANY (x IN nodes(p) 
                                              WHERE x.cd='130114')
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: may I ask you how much db hits you have, because my second query has only 6 db hits ?

Comment: May I ask what structure you would choice? I saw something similar in one of the talks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjQyffPSWJk#t=1205